# How to link a specific part of a particular page?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Like these words 'the human eye has less dynamic range' in the 2<sup>nd</sup> footnote of this 1<sup>st</sup> answer to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39310/why-is-my-camera-so-forgiving-for-overblown-exposure-when-shooting-in-raw/39315#39315) are linked to that Wikipedia's 'Dynamic Range' part of the 'Human Eye' page, how to link a specific part of a page?

Comment: for wiki page? or in SO/SE pages?

Comment: want to know how to link anypage...

Comment: So this is off topic here. Meta Stack Exchange is only for questions about Stack Exchange, not general question of "how to do things".

Answer (score 7):

You can't, at least not inside Stack Exchange. You can only link to specific *answers* (by clicking the share button under the answer) or *comments* (by clicking the 'age' link at the end of the comment – thanks @PeterMortensen), not to specific *parts* in the answer.

The `name` and `id` HTML attributes [aren't supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/295232), so you can't even create [anchors](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) inside your own posts.

Comment: Sometimes you want to link to a specific part of a post. In this case to the _`Allowed attributes for <a>`_. As workaround you can use the somewhat [controversial](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/privacy-concerns-raised-over-new-google-chrome-feature/) [Scroll To Text Fragment](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment)/[Copy Link to Highlight](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10256233) feature: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites/135909#135909:~:text=Allowed%20attributes%20for%20%3Ca%3E (not in Brave)

Answer (score 2):

If a page supports bookmarks then you can link it in your answer. In case of a Wikipedia page it supports bookmark links in its content section.

[image]

When you click on any of the links, it will drag you to the specific title. Then you can copy paste the link from the URL tab of the browser and then paste it in your answer.